# How to sort a bound ObjectDataProvider Collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, binding, enums

I populate a `ListBox` with the `Description` values of an `Enum`. The are displayed in the index order of the `Enum`, but I want them sorted by description. So I added a `SortDescription` to the `ListBox`, but it doesn't work.

```
ObjectDataProvider odp = new ObjectDataProvider()
{
  IsInitialLoadEnabled = false,
  MethodName = "GetValues",
  ObjectType = typeof(Enum),
};
odp.MethodParameters.Add(this.EnumType);
odp.Refresh();
Binding b = new Binding() { Source = odp };
listBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
listBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription());
```

I also tried to add a property name to the `SortDescription`, but I don't know which one (I tried 'Value' and 'Description').

Wrapping the `ObjectDataProvider` in an `CollectionViewSource` and sorting that collection doesn't help either.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the purpose of `ObjectDataProvider`, if your binding is in code?

```
var sortedValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    .Cast<MyEnum>()
    .OrderBy(v => v.ToString())
    .ToArray();

Binding b = new Binding() { Source = sortedValues };
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The code was in XAML once and was moved for some reason. Can't remember why anymore. The last `ToArray()` isn't neccesary.